# Angular ng repeat filter, ignore when empty value

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this select

```
<select ng-model="applicationStatus" ng-options="p.StatusID as p.Status for p in vm.projects | unique:'StatusID'">
        <option value="">All</option>
 </select>
```

And a list below that use the selected value as a filter:

```
<tr ng-repeat="p in vm.projects | filter: {StatusID:applicationStatus}">
```

This works, except when "All" is selected in the list (the predefined value)
When "All" is selected I don't want the filter to be applied. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could have something like below, which will place `''` blank instead of nothing.

```
<tr ng-repeat="p in vm.projects | filter: {StatusID:(applicationStatus || '')}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to create a custom filter to handle this scenario.  Here's a good post about how to create one:

[AngularJS filter by select with empty options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27117880/angularjs-filter-by-select-with-empty-options/27118166#27118166)